# Draggable Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to create a Bootstrap popover that follows a draggable image (using jQuery UI Draggable library). By "follows", I mean that if the image is dragged 10 pixels right, the popover also moves 10 pixels right. The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to link the Bootstrap popover to the image. The 'container' parameter on the popover intializer doesn't seem to work (ideally, I would like to put the image and the popover in a parent div and make that div draggable). I'm not sure what the best way to go about doing this is? Elegant solutions would be great, but a hacky one is better than nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work..

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').each(function () {
        // hide any open popovers when the anywhere else in the body is clicked
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});

$("[data-toggle=popover]").mousedown(function(){
  // toggle popover when link is clicked
  $(this).popover('toggle');
});

$("[data-toggle=popover]").draggable({
  stop:function(){
    // show popover when drag stops
    $(this).popover('show');
  }
});
```

This assumes you want to show the popover when the container (link) is 'clicked'. The popover will toggle when the link is clicked, or show when dragging stops.

Also, a link (a href) has to be used to contain the draggable. If you want to make the link look like a div set it's CSS to `display:block`.

### [Demo: http://bootply.com/61825](http://bootply.com/61825)

Comment: @zim How can i draggable popover itself. How can we do this?